# How to get one average value by one request to graphite

Tags: grafana, graphite

Let's say, we have graphite running on some hostname.

I can get 10 values from it by this request:

http://hostname/render?target=wm.compName.cpu&from=-10min&until=now&format=json&cacheTimeout=0&maxDataPoints=100

Response:

[{"target":"wm.compName.cpu","datapoints":[[49.95077854394913,1570188060],[51.01308137178421,1570188120],[52.00076638907194,1570188180],[52.50447646342218,1570188240],[54.03549341484904,1570188300],[53.18660210818052,1570188360],[53.88282400369644,1570188420],[53.19335952401161,1570188480],[53.58670086041093,1570188540],[53.73451334635417,1570188600]],"tags":{"name":"wm.compName.cpu"}}]

Can anyone tell me, how to create request, that will return from hostname ONLY ONE value (average from this 10 values)?

Any help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways:

- [movingAverage(metric,10)](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.movingAverage) if you want to continuously get an average of the last ten datapoints,
- [summarize(metric,10,avg,true/false)](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) if you want to group or "roll up" every ten datapoints into one average datapoint.

Comment: Sorry for annoying, but may be you now how to subtract this average value from constant value, like 100 for example ?
I tried diffSeries(100, metric), but it doesnt work this way

Comment: To subtract from a constant like 100 you would need to use offset(metric,-100) which subtracts 100 from the metric, and wrap that in an absolute() function to get the absolute value. It should look like: absolute(offset(metric,-100)).

To divide by 4 you would use the scale() function with value 0.25 like so:
scale(absolute(offset(metric, -100)),0.25)

[offset](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.offset)
[scale](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.scale)